# Constraint on column to set limit of possible values

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints

I need to put a constraint on a column so that it can only contain the following range of values

```
Allowed values: between 1 and 10
Column Data Type: tinyint
DBMS or Docker Image: Microsoft SQL Server - mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest
```

I believe it should be something close to this

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projects]
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_val_limit CHECK (Priority in (between 1 and 10))
GO
```

Comment: You might want to use `ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projects]
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_val_limit CHECK (Priority BETWEEN 1 AND 10);` just remove `in`

Comment: @D-Shih Thanks, I searched all over the internet and didn't find anything, but you solved it in a few minutes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one!

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Projects]
ADD CONSTRAINT chk_val_limit CHECK (ColumnName > 1 AND ColumnName < 10)
GO
```

Comment: OP - I hope you understand that this "answer" is not inclusive of the lower and upper bounds while `BETWEEN` as suggested in the comments (and your initial attempt) is.